# Does the blow-up preserve symplectic structure?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, contact-geometry, holomorphic-symplectic

Let $X \subset \mathbb P(\mathfrak g)$ be an adjoint variety for a simple complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ appearing in the last line of the Freudenthal Magic Square, that is $\mathfrak g \in \{F_4,E_6,E_7,E_8\}$. In particular $\dim X=6m+9$ where $m \in \{1,2,4,8\}$. Consider minimal embedding of the VMRT of $X$ at a point $x$, that is
$$
Y^{3m+3} \subset \mathbb P^{6m+7} \subset \mathbb P^{6m+8}=\mathbb P(T_{X,x}).
$$
On the other hand we have the contact structure $0 \to F \to T_X \to L \to 0$, and the restriction of such a sequence to $x$ allow us to write $Y \subset \mathbb P(F_x)$.

Now, $F_x$ is endowed with a symplectic form $\omega$ that is the restriction to $F_x$ of the map $\omega=d\theta: F \times F \to L$. In particular $\mathbb P(F_x)$ has a symplectic structure.
We blow-up $\mathbb P(F_x)$ along $Y$, obtaining a map
$$
b: Bl_Y \mathbb P(F_x) \longrightarrow \mathbb P(F_x).
$$
Question: do the map $b$ preserve the symplectic structure? More precisely, can we define a symplectic structure on $Bl_Y \mathbb P(F_x)$?

Any hint of a possible argument for the proof?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, a blow up never has a holomorphic symplectic structure. The canonical bundle of a holomorphic symplectic manifold is trivial. The restriction of the canonical bundle to the exceptional fibre is non-trivial, which may be seen by computing $c_1$ of it.

Comment: @NickL: well, $\mathbb P(F_x)$ is a projective space and it has also a symplectic structure, but its canonical bundle is not trivial...

Comment: A projective space dos not have a holomorphic symplectic structure, since its canonical bundle is non-trivial, it has a real symplectic structure ( as any Kahler manifold does), but I  assumed since you used the "holomorphic symplectic" tag that is what you meant?

Comment: Sorry, I used the tag because my final goal is to prove the existence of a Mukai flop, which appears on the list of arguments of the tag "holomorphic symplectic". Everything is on the complex numbers, since I have chosen $\mathfrak g$ to be a complex simple Lie algebra

Comment: Ok, are you asking about the existence of a real symplectic structure or a holomorphic symplectic structure?

Comment: No, I'm asking about the existence of a complex symplectic structure

Comment: Again: $\Bbb{P}(F_x)$ has **no** (complex) symplectic structure.

Comment: @abx maybe a stupid question: any chance for the exceptional divisor?

Comment: Any chance for what? For having a symplectic structure? Nick L has already answered this (negatively).

Comment: When you say complex symplectic structure, do you mean holomorphic? (Just to double check.)